# FSharp Compound List

Tags: f#

What's the cleanest & simplest way to create this 'compound' list in F#?

Input:

```
[ 1; 2; 3; 4; 5 ]
```

Desired Output:

```
[ [1]; [1;2]; [1;2;3]; [1,2,3,4]; [1;2;3;4;5] ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways but I think this is a clean one:

```
[1;2;3;4;5]  
    |> List.scan (fun x y -> x @ [y]) [] 
    |> List.tail
```

using `List.scan` and finally `List.tail` to omit the first element which is an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way interpreting the contents strictly as ints and using list comprehension:

```
[1; 2; 3; 4; 5] |> List.map(fun n -> [ for i = 1 to n do yield i ])
```

And you get the same output as above, but if your input is this:

```
[2; 1; 2] |> List.map(fun n -> [ for i = 1 to n do yield i ])
```

You get:

```
[[1; 2]; [1]; [1; 2]]
```

Which may or may not be what you want.